# an adjective for a tall line!

Tags: word-request

Suppose these two lines

> ======
>
> =============================

I say the first line is short, it's a short line!

what can I say for the second line? tall line?! big line? large line?

---

*update:* oops! maybe *long line*, I missed that. to make it a proper question what about **lengthy line**?!

Comment: "Long line". "Long" is an opposite of "short".

Comment: @MorganFR right, I forgot that.

Comment: Down vote means that I should delete this question?!

Comment: I don't know about that downvote, but there are many reasons, justified or not, that can result in downvotes (e.g. research done, purpose...). As for the question in your update, "lengthy" relates more to either considerable or unusual length, not that something is simply long. Try no to overcomplicate things too much for something as banal as this, and stick to the obvious "long".

Comment: @MorganFR sure, just I liked to know the difference! long is enough for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *long line*, *long* is opposite of *short*.

[Dictionary Link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/long)

> Measuring a great distance from end to end:
>
> "a long corridor"
>
> "long black hair"
>
> "the queue for tickets was long"